# Windows Service Bus - Rename topic?

Tags: c#, servicebus

Using Windows Serives Bus (not the cloud version), I'm trying to rename a topic programatically, so far I have

```
    internal void UpdateTopic(Topic Topic)
    {
            Topic dbTopic = TopicManager.GetTopicById(Topic.Id);
            TopicDescription topicDescription = _namespaceManager.GetTopic(dbTopic.Name);
            topicDescription.Path = Topic.Name;
            topicDescription.Status = Topic.Active ? EntityStatus.Active : EntityStatus.Disabled;
            _namespaceManager.UpdateTopic(topicDescription);
            ...
```

The line `_namespaceManager.UpdateTopic(topicDescription);` throws Exception `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. Not Found.TrackingId:[some tracking id including a GUID],TimeStamp:20/12/2013 13:29:47`

Questions:
- Can I actually rename a topic programmatically?
If yes:
- Any idea of what causes the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename of a Topic is not supported. You can do Create, Update and Delete operations but since the name is the identifier of the particular resource it cannot be modified. There are several other properties on a `TopicDescription`too that cannot be modified, but only set at the time of creation (such as `Size`).